# How to Scan DynamoDb Not Exists

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using Laravel DynamoDB using this git Repo

https://github.com/baopham/laravel-dynamodb

I want to query not exists

tried this did not work

```
$logs = $ShopperLogs->where('date', '>=', $from)->where('date', '<=', $to)->where('op_city_id', 'Not Exists')->get();
```

and tried this, also did not work

```
$logs = $ShopperLogs->where('date', '>=', $from)->where('date', '<=', $to)->where('op_city_id', null)->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**whereNull() and whereNotNull()**

> > NULL and NOT_NULL only check for the attribute presence not its value
> >     being null
>
> See:
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html

```
$model->whereNull('name');
$model->whereNotNull('name');
```

Reference: [laravel-dynamodb](https://github.com/baopham/laravel-dynamodb)

Answer (score 1):

try `->whereNull('op_city_id')`